# Any way to optimize or improve this python combinations/subsets functions?

Tags: python, functional-programming, combinatorics

I believe this is essentially the same method as the `itertools.combinations` function, but is there any way to make this code more more perfect in terms of speed, code size and readability :

```
def all_subsets(source,size):
        index = len(source)
        index_sets = [()]
        for sz in xrange(size):
                next_list = []
                for s in index_sets:
                        si = s[len(s)-1] if len(s) > 0 else -1
                        next_list += [s+(i,) for i in xrange(si+1,index)]
                index_sets = next_list
        subsets = []
        for index_set in index_sets:
                rev = [source[i] for i in index_set]
                subsets.append(rev)
        return subsets
```

Yields:

```
>>> Apriori.all_subsets(['c','r','i','s'],2)
[['c', 'r'], ['c', 'i'], ['c', 's'], ['r', 'i'], ['r', 's'], ['i', 's']]
```

There is probably a way to use generators or functional concepts, hopefully someone can suggest improvements.

Comment: Why aren't you using itertools.combinations? It's reasonable to do this for learning purposes, but if you are actually doing a bigger project you'll want to use the itertools version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems lend themselves very well to [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). A possible implementation, either in list or generator form could be:

```
def all_subsets(di, i) :
    ret = []
    for j, item in enumerate(di) :
        if i == 1 :
            ret = [(j,) for j in di]
        elif len(di) - j >= i :
            for subset in all_subsets(di[j + 1:], i - 1) :
                ret.append((item,) + subset)
    return ret

def all_subsets_gen(di, i) :
    for j, item in enumerate(di) :
        if i == 1 :
            yield (j,)
        elif len(di) - j >= i :
            for subset in all_subsets(di[j + 1:], i - 1) :
                yield (item,) + subset

>>> all_subsets(range(4), 3)
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> list(all_subsets_gen(range(4), 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

If you are going to run this on large sets, you may want to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) intermediate results to speed things up.

Comment: RE the memorization, do you mean if the function is going to be run more than once? Otherwise I don't see how memorization would help here, since isn't there only *one path* down through the recursion, with each size of subsets being created just once?

Comment: @CrisStringfellow In my example above, the `(0, 2, 3)` and the `(1, 2, 3)` are both calling `all_subsets([2, 3], 2)` and it gets worse for larger sets, especially with a small `i`.

Comment: Got it. I was wrong. But couldn't that be subtly changed by making the call to 2,3 and then prepending the first element/s? Is this what you mean by memorization?